# Chromedriver error in Selenium rails tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, rspec, selenium-chromedriver

Attempting to run rspec tests written by some other developers. But the tests are failing with the following error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515

  0) /media/uploader product video wistia uploads adds video when links is valid
     Failure/Error: visit login_path

     Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError:
       unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
```

The gemfile does not contain the `chromedriver-helper` gem but that shouldn't be a problem, as other developers have been able to run the tests successfully without the gem in the gemfile. I've tried brew installing chromedriver but that hasn't helped. I suspect the issue has something to do with the fact that the repo is using ruby 2.2.8, but chromedriver, for some reason, is only available with 2.4.2.

```
asahmed:~/Documents/workspace/vendor-portal-next (master) $ chromedriver -v
rbenv: chromedriver: command not found

The `chromedriver' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.4.2
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 5):

I have had a similar issue, it was a result of being unable to get rid of the rbenv chromedriver shim. Following the steps in this comment fixed it for me.

In my case the gemfile did contain chromedriver-helper, but in case it is the same issue I thought I would comment.

https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper/issues/44#issuecomment-358743719

The steps are:

First check if

```
❯ which chromedriver
```

returns

```
~/.rbenv/shims/chromedriver
```

if so try

```
❯ ls ~/.rbenv/versions/*/bin/* | grep chromedriver
```

to get the list of chromedriver executables on disc.

Then remove those executables with

```
❯ rm [path to chromedriver and chromedriver-update executables]
```

Finally run

```
❯ rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an old version of the `chromedriver-helper` gem installed (in Ruby 2.4.2), which supplies a `chromedriver` executable -- that is appearing in your PATH before your "real" `chromedriver` installed by `brew`.

To solve the problem, you can either:

- uninstall the gem causing the problem: `rbenv shell 2.4.2; gem uninstall chromedriver-helper` -- this will fix it for now, but it might come back if it's mentioned by some other project's Gemfile
- install an old version of `chromedriver-helper` in your running ruby: `gem install chromedriver-helper -v 1.2.0`
- somehow convince the `brew`-supplied executable to be preferred over the `rbenv` one

I'd recommend going for option 1, and chasing down any other projects and bumping their `chromedriver-helper` to 2.0+.